# wampserver and magento 2 installed on local server

Tags: magento-2.0, 404, wamp

I get an error 404 when I run Magento on my local host

I have named my domain as rednsoft

Magento is running on wampserver

Comment: Did you check your configuration of magento database and env.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the value of PHP `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` from `php.ini` file.

Also, I had written a very nice tutorial which will give you an ease to install Magento 2 on localhost. Please check out the tutorial here:

https://blog.amasty.com/how-to-install-magento-2-php7-localhost/